# Connecting to Oracle on Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, visual-studio-2010, odbc

I have installed Oracle Client 10g 32 bit and ODAC 11g R2 on my Windows 7 machine, but I cannot see any Oracle Providers in MS ODBC Administration or when I try to created a linked server to Oralce in SQL Server Management Studio or in Visual Studio 2010. Can anyone please help me out as what to do? I can connect to Oracle server through SQLPlus but get errors when connecting through VS 2010 using MS providers for Oracle.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the Oracle Client, did you also install the ODBC driver? IOW, did you do a custom install and add in the ODBC driver? Unless you do a full client install the ODBC drivers are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying if your windows 7 installation is 32 or 64 bit.

If it's 32 bit then see the previous answer, restart Oracle installer and check that ODBC is selected.

If it's 64 bit I advise you to install both the Oracle client in 32 bit (as you did) and also the Oracle 11 client in 64 bit, so that you can use the proper library.

In any case I still haven't found a proper way to perform Oracle installation on Windows 7 (64 bit) that works for every client and tool combination, good luck.

Comment: I have Win 7 32 bit with oracle client 10g 32 bit with odac 11g which has backward compatibility with 10g client.

Comment: sorry i have win 7 64 bit oracle client 10g 32 bit with odac 11g

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while too, best solution I found was here:

http://dotnetcrap.blogspot.com/2009/08/oracle-client-on-windows-7.html

Comment: This post doesn't tell how to get the provider strings into sql server for oledb / odbc for the linked servers to be created. Because I am not not using Ora Client 11g, I do not need to go through the fix, I am just running ODAC 11g which installs fine on Windows 7. I am using Oracle 10g client.